# Adding registry entries at the top in windows registry key c#

Tags: c#, registry

i would like to add my registry entries always on top of the list, for example if 10 registry  entries in run key  , i would like to place my registry entry at the top of the key.

Comment: MSalters is right.  There is no "top of the key".

Answer (score 1):

To quote Raymond Chen: "What if two applications would try to do that?"

Anyway, the registry isn't ordered. Some *views* are.

(Let me source that: [RegEnumKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724862.aspx) : "Because subkeys are not ordered, any new subkey will have an arbitrary index. This means that the function may return subkeys in any order."

Answer (score 0):

That won't probably change anything, but you could add a couple of underscore (or any character before 'A') before the value name.

But that's only how the Windows Registry is displaying them. Today, Windows is using startup optimization and it might change the order of which the programs start when Windows starts to provide the best experience to the user.

You should not rely on the program order in Run.